# Excel, deleting columns with Zero value and graphing 1000's of points

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with 1000's points that I want to graph.
Y axis are dates, X axis is time,  values are electricity consumption in Kwh.
As you can see updates are in 15min intervals but every other is 0.
a) I want to delete the 0 columns.
b) And graph the result > 255points
[excel.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGWvF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To delete every other column without doing it manually, you can create a formula to help.  First insert a row at the top of the sheet (you will delete this row when you are done with it.)  Next, in your new helper row, add a MOD function to the first column with the Kwh values (probably column B.)  This returns a remainder after we make a division, so we pass the column function to it as our number parameter.  The other parameter is the divisor so we will use 2 for that.

=MOD(COLUMN(),2)

With the cell selected, click the bottom right square of the green highlight of that cell (when your cursor turns to a +) and drag it across all of your columns.  Now we will have a 0 and 1 in every other column.

We want to convert that formula to values to make sure nothing happens to our data so now copy the highlighted cells and right click to paste special.  Here you will change the Paste radio button to Values.

Now we have values in the helper row so we can select all of our columns except the date row, so do that and open the data column.   Click the Sort icon and in the sort window now you will click options and choose from left to right.  We will then choose to sort by row 1, and choose the order to be smallest to largest.

Now when you click  to sort you will have all of your columns with 0 in them (if it was indeed every other column) on the right-hand side, and all of your data is in the left.  Easily select all of the zero rows now and delete them manually with one click.  Also delete the helper row you created and you have the sheet ready to graph.

Select all of your data including column A and Row 1, and then go to the insert tab.  In charts you can see the different types of graphs.  Check the recommended charts or experiment by clicking on the different types of graphs to see which one fits your needs the best.  If you choose the 2 Line or Scatter for instance, it will graph out each day in different colors showing Kwh on the Y axis, and X will be the time.  You can then format as you wish.